# Bloquear impressão via menu "Imprimir" com macro

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de bloquear a impressão de uma planilha pelo menu Arquivo-Imprimir (Ctrl+P) ou pelo ícone da impressora, através de uma macro. Pois, fiz uma macro que ao apertar um botão ela fará um comportamento na planilha e mandará imprimir automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Insira o código em `EstaPastaDeTrabalho` ou `ThisWorkbook` em inglês:

[image: Esta pasta de Trabalho]

Em que o evento `Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)` é utilizado.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If imprimir Then
        Cancel = False
    Else
        MsgBox ("Você não possui permissão para imprimir.")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

E um teste para imprimir com o código num Módulo:

```
Public imprimir As Boolean
Sub teste_impressao()
    imprimir = True
    Planilha1.PrintOut
End Sub
Sub teste_nao_impressao()
    Planilha1.PrintOut
End Sub
```